# Ensure a single instance of Telerik Window per page/request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have an **EditorTemplate** that is repeated on a page. This EditorTemplate creates a Telerik Window (see code below).  How do I ensure that only one instance of the `PostalLookupWindow` Window is created for a given page/request?  I want to re-use this Window for all the EditorTemplates.

I have tried using ViewData and TempData to store temporary values indicating that the control has been created before but was unsuccessful.

I cannot put the Window creation in the controls's parent as the EditorTemplate is re-used in multiple pages.

```
 Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("PostalLookupWindow")
    .Title("Postal Code Selection")
    .Height(430)
    .Width(700)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Scrollable(false)
    .LoadContentFrom(Url.Action("Index","PostalCode", null, Request.Url.Scheme))
    .Visible(false).Render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [`HttpContext.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) to store a value. There is only one instance of that collection for the entire request.